# How to fetch certificate from keyvault?

Tags: asp.net-core, certificate, azure-keyvault

If the `pfx` file is stored in the file share it's easy:

```
new X509Certificate2(certificateFilePath, certificatePassword);
```

but how can I construct a `X509Certificate2` object for a certificate that is stored in Azure Keyvault? I can't find any samples for that. I've got the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` for the keyvault.

Answer (score 3):

I created this `AzureKeyvaultHelper` class (I'm still on .NET 4.8 - but I believe this should also work on .NET Core):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace AzureUtils
{
    public class AzureKeyvaultHelper
    {
        private readonly string _tenantId;
        private readonly string _clientId;
        private readonly string _clientSecret;

        public AzureKeyvaultHelper(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            _clientId = clientId;
            _clientSecret = clientSecret;
            _tenantId = tenantId;
        }

        public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string vaultName, string certName)
        {
            ClientSecretCredential credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(_tenantId, _clientId, _clientSecret);
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultName), credentials);

            KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret(certName);
            byte[] certificate = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);

            X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(certificate);

            return x509;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to

- include the `Azure.Identity` and `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets` nuget packages
- provide a tenant id, client id and client secret to the constructor to get the `SecretClient` (defined in `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets` - for keyvault) up and running

The trick to get the certificate fully - including its private parts as in the `*.pfx` file - is to **not** use the `client.GetCertificate` call - but instead the `client.GetSecret` call. The `GetCertificate` call will only return the public parts of the certificate and strip out any private components.

The `vaultName` to pass in is something like `https://yourcustomname.vault.azure.net`, and the `certName` has to match the name you gave the certificate in Azure Keyvault.

Comment: I'm curious so it is not possible to call secret and certificate the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Support was added to `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates` in v4.2.0 on June 16, 2021:

> The functions CertificateClient.DownloadCertificate and CertificateClient.DownloadCertificateAsync were added in Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates 4.2.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/get-certificate-private-key/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.certificates.certificateclient.downloadcertificateasync?view=azure-dotnet